# Service doesn't show Logs

Tags: android, logging, service, android-intent

**Question**

---

I got a little problem to see what happens in my Service. I don't get any logs of it. So first I thought I probably don't start my Service, but this isn't the problem. When I go to Running-Apps on my Device the Service is listed up there.

Now lets take a look at the Code:

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.ivocore"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IVOCore"
        android:debuggable="true">

        <service android:name=".service.DataHandlerService" />
          <!--    android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        android:process=":DataHandler" -->

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".LoginActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="de.ivocore.LOGINCHECK"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>    

    </application>


        <!-- Definieren welche Permission's die Applikation besitzt -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.class

I start the Service here in my onCreate().

```
package de.ivocore;

import de.ivocore.service.DataHandlerService;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String LOAD_ORDER = "de.ivocore.MainActivity.LOAD_ORDER";

    //Verschiedene Integer definieren für Switch/Case damit der Service weis was zu tun ist
    int FIRST_LOAD = 0; //Wird gesendet beim onCreate der Activity
    int RELOAD = 1; //Wird gesendet wenn der User einen reload möchte

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Service starten zusätlich wird folgender Parameter mitgegeben "onstart" 
        //dies zeigt dem Service das die Activity gerade gestartet wurde.
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DataHandlerService.class);
        i.putExtra(LOAD_ORDER, FIRST_LOAD);
        startService(i);
    }



    public void onReceive(Intent intent){

    }
}
```

DataHandlerService.class

Here i catch the Intent over onStartCommand(), which probably dosn't work. But I don't get whats wrong there...

```
public class DataHandlerService extends Service {
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private Calendar calendar;
    private static final int PERIOD = 60000 * 60; // 1h
    private final String LOAD_VIDEO = "de.ivocore.service.DataHandlerService.LOAD_VIDEO";
    private final String LOAD_ORDER = "de.ivocore.MainActivity.LOAD_ORDER";

    LoginAdapter mDbHelper = new LoginAdapter(this);

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    public void onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, String startID){
        int load = intent.getIntExtra(LOAD_ORDER, 0);
        Log.d("DataHandlerService",  "Activity startet mit folgendem Parameter ="+load);

        switch (load){
        case 0:
            Log.d("DataHandlerService", "Es wird def OfficeTimerOnStart gestartet");
            checkOfficeTimeOnStart();
        break;
        case 1:
            getOrders();
        break;
        }



    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

---

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, that I can see my Logs!

Thank you in Advance.

Best Regards

safari

Comment: I was facing the same issue on a huawei device. I had to change to another device cause I dind't find any other solution. Once changed I was able to see the log. Maybe a setting on developper settings might have do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be having problems to use DDMS Logging feature.
Try to get the logs in a file to your filesystem and search for your logs.

```
1 > Go to command prompt.
2 > Traverse to the platform tools dir of your SDK location
3 > type " adb logcat > D:\log.txt

------
4. After starting your app exit the logcat by pressing ctrl+c
```

then try to verify the presence of your logs.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it doesn't work for me. It only writes logs of usual code in Activity, not from Service. I write logs like this: Log.d("MyTag", "MyIntentService.onCreate");

Comment: I have a similar issue but from within a SyncAdapter service that logs only the first time I call Log.d or Timber.d then nothing but the adb logcat stuff did the trick !

Answer (score 9):

This is quite old post, but I ended here anyway, when I had the same problem in Android Studio. For those who will end up here just like me, following might be the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you select the Log level as debug? If not please do so in Eclipse debug prespective

Comment: i meant in eclipse debug perspective you need to select the debug level

Comment: Try giving the full qualified name of the Service class in manifest file